# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMagick++6-Q16

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, compilation, imagemagick

I have installed ImageMagick library (from source) on ubuntu system (12.04):

```
$: identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.3-6 2013-03-02 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: ps
```

But if I tried to compilate my program:

```
$: make
g++ -o grayscale grayscale.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6.8 -I/usr/local/lib `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMagick++6-Q16
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMagick++6-Q16
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [grayscale] Error 1
```

I've tried looking for some solutions but couldn't fix this. Can you anybody help me? I don't properly understanding what does this error means.

Comment: Could you post the output of ls `/usr/local/lib | grep Magick`, also try to link directly like this `-limagemagick++`.

Comment: root@charles:/home/ImageMagick-6.8.3-6# ls /usr/local/lib | grep Magick


ImageMagick-6.8.3
libMagick++-6.Q16.a
libMagick++-6.Q16.la
libMagick++-6.Q16.so
libMagick++-6.Q16.so.1
libMagick++-6.Q16.so.1.0.0
libMagickCore-6.Q16.a
libMagickCore-6.Q16.la
libMagickCore-6.Q16.so
libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.1
libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.1.0.0
libMagickWand-6.Q16.a
libMagickWand-6.Q16.la
libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.1
libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.1.0.0

Comment: Try this: `g++ -o grayscale grayscale.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6.8 -L/usr/local/lib -lMagick++-6.Q16`.

Comment: Tahnks mate, this works with no errors for me: g++ -o grayscale grayscale.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6.8 -I/usr/local/lib -lMagick++-6.Q16 `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags`

Comment: For lib directory add `-L`, like this: `-L/usr/local/lib`