# cannot find -lMagick++-6.Q16

Tags: c++, r, gcc, compilation, imagemagick

I try to install `magick` R package but I get error:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/path/apps/R/3.5.1-20180807-test/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib64/R/lib -L/path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib -Wl,--exclude-libs,libz.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libbz2.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libcurl.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libpcre.a -Wl,--as-needed -o magick.so RcppExports.o animation.o attributes.o base.o color.o composite.o config.o convolve.o device.o edit.o fonts.o options.o properties.o resize.o transformations.o -L/path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib/ /path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib/libcurl.a /path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib/libz.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libz.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libcurl.a -lidn -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -lrt -lcairo -L/path/apps/mysql/5.7.11/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl -L/path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm -ldl -L/path/apps/V8/3.14/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib64 -L/path/apps/openmpi/1.8.1/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/gnu/lsf/lib -L/path/apps/imagemagick/7.0.7-8/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib/pkgconfig -lMagick++-6.Q16 -L/path/apps/R/3.5.1-20180807-test/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMagick++-6.Q16
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [magick.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘magick’
```

My `LIB_DIR` and `INCLUDE_DIR` looks like that:

```
export LIB_DIR="$STATIC_LIB/lib/ $STATIC_LIB/lib/libcurl.a \
$STATIC_LIB/lib/libz.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libz.a \
-Wl,--exclude-libs,libcurl.a -lidn -lssl -lcrypto -lldap -lrt \
-lcairo $MYSQL_LIBS $XML2_LIBS -L$V8_LIBS \
-L$MPI_HOME/lib \
-L/path/apps/imagemagick/7.0.7-8/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib/pkgconfig"

export INCLUDE_DIR="$STATIC_LIB/include -I/usr/include/cairo \
-I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 \
-I/usr/include/libpng12 \
-I$MPI_HOME/include \
-I/path/apps/imagemagick/7.0.7-8/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/include/ImageMagick-7"
```

`include` contains:

```
ls /path/apps/imagemagick/7.0.7-8/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/include/ImageMagick-7
Magick++  MagickCore  Magick++.h  MagickWand
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170344/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lmagick6-q16) but my `lib` directory contains similar set of files:

```
ls /path/apps/imagemagick/7.0.7-8/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib/
ImageMagick-7.0.7               libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.4
libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.a         libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.la        libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.a
libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so        libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.la
libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so.3      libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so
libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so.3.0.0  libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.4
libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.a       libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0
libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.la      pkgconfig
libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so
```

I'm using `imagemagick 7` so why it still requires some flag/arg `-lMagick++-6.Q16` from version `6`?

Comment: You wrote `-lMagick++-6.Q16` on the very first line, so that's what it looks for.

Comment: Looks like RMagick needs IM 6 not IM 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to install `magick`. I compiled ImageMagick v6 from [source](https://www.imagemagick.org/download/6.9.10-10.tar.gz) and installed R package with following set of env variables:

```
STATIC_LIB="/path/static-zlib-gcc6.3"
IMAGEMAGICK_V6_HOME="/path/ImageMagick-6.9.10-10"

export LIB_DIR="$STATIC_LIB/lib/ \
-L$IMAGEMAGICK_V6_HOME/lib"

export INCLUDE_DIR="$STATIC_LIB/include \
-DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 \
-I$IMAGEMAGICK_V6_HOME/include/ImageMagick-6"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$IMAGEMAGICK_V6_HOME/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IMAGEMAGICK_V6_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

If `pkg-config` and `Magick++-config` are not available, the `magick` package [defaults to ImageMagick v6](https://github.com/ropensci/magick/blob/029e49cf5ac188ee3a5cddf7e519d0e8766cffb1/configure#L15):

```
PKG_LIBS="-lMagick++-6.Q16"
```

So you will have to install version 6. In addition you might also [report an issue](https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues) asking to support version 7 in the case of a installation without `pkg-config/Magick++-config`.

Alternatively you can try to get `pkg-config/Magick++-config` working on your machine. If `pkg-config/Magick++-config` can be used, the flags provided from there are used directly.